# Add a column that increments when another column changes

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have table like

```
id status other columns
-- ------ -------------
1  f
2  f
3  t
4  t
5  t
6  f
```

Now, when I select the table I wan to add specific column and to check when status has change. The result should be something like:

```
id status other columns status_index
-- ------ ------------- ------------
1  f                         1
2  f                         1
3  t                         2
4  t                         2
5  t                         2
6  f                         3
```

Query should be for postgres.

Comment: What did you try so far? Question is unclear to me.

Comment: Question is pretty interesting, but add more precise title next time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
with cte as (
    select
        *,
        row_number() over(order by id) as rn1,
        row_number() over(partition by status order by id) as rn2
    from Table1
)
select
    id, status,
    dense_rank() over(order by rn1 - rn2) as status_index
from cte
order by id
```

**<kbd>[sql fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/ba4c8/3)</kbd>**

Comment: Thnx Roman Pekar, your answer helped me.